# Site Indexed in Yahoo and Bing but not Google

Tags: google, google-search, bing, yahoo, google-ranking

I have a site `www.holiday-tuscany.com` that has been online for less than a month.

If you put the keyword *Holiday Tuscany* in Google the site doesn't appear in any of Google rankings. If I do the same search on Yahoo or Bing the site is in the first page around the world except USA and UK where is in 3 or 4 page. Why is this?

Comment: The site is index, just you have no rankings http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=www.holiday-tuscany.com improve your off page SEO and wait..

Answer (score 1):

Google lowered the ranking score given to sites for exact match domains, especially for new sites. The Yahoo and Bing search engine more than likely still rewards for EMD (Exact Mach Domain). Since your site is new, it hasn't had time to build a competitive edge in Google's serps for that keyword combination.

To clarify, your site does appear in Google's serp, just not in the way you wish it would.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add your site to Google Webmaster Tools. I think there's an option to prompt Google bots to visit your site. Also make sure your `robots.txt` file accommodates for Google's bot.